# How to unhide the icons disappeared from the action bar?

Tags: google-sheets

I lost all the icons from my action bar.  Some very faint vestiges of the action bars are still visible. I know the action bars are still there, by hovering over the positions; the tooltips would appear.  But the pull down menues from those action bar items do not show up.

I do not know what caused this, possibly I accidentally hitting some key combination.

This happens only in my Chrome browser.  In Edge browser the action bar icons are visible as normal.
[image: This is what I see for the action bar]

Edited to clarify after aviboy2006 question. My problem is with the bar below  the bar starting with File. Not with the menu bar starting with File.  Hope you can see: the icons (on the bar below File) are not visible.

Comment: you are talking above file / edit /view menu ? or actual one where bold/italic/ font selection option is there ?

Comment: If it happens only in Chrome, maybe you accidentally installed some [Chrome https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=enextension]() that interferes with your action bar?

Comment: some Chrome extension

Comment: As somebody speculated, it was I had a extension, which had the images off.  The action bar icons are images.  It got enabled on my google sheet accidentally, that is why I did not know the cause.  Once I disabled that extension from the google sheet tab of the browser, the icons are back.